# Kentico "Editable Web Parts" appearing in page under "Edit Regions & Web Parts"

Tags: web-parts, kentico

I have a bunch of pages that I or other content editors have added Web Parts to via the Design tab in the Pages app. The Web Parts appear to function correctly when I view the page.

Every so often I get a note from a content editor that they are seeing stale content on the page. Sure enough, when I log into the CMS and go to the pages app and view the Page preview tab, I see old content.  I then go to the Design tab and edit the Web Part they are looking at, I **do** see their new content appear in the Web Part form controls. Very strange. I have not set up any caching on the page, or these Web Parts.

After poking around a bit, I found the "Edit Regions & Web Parts" under the General tab in the Pages app. It's beneath an "Advanced" label. I open this up and I see a window labeled "Editable content" showing two lists "Editable web parts" and "Editable regions".  Everytime a content editor has shown me examples of this stale content, there is an item listed under "Editable web parts", and when I open up that item, it has the "stale" content that the editor is complaining about. It seems to override whatever content is actually assigned to the Web Part in the Design tab. I delete the item from the list, and the page suddenly shows the correct content again.

**How is this "Editable web parts" list controlled in Kentico?**. What actions create items in this list?

I have hundreds of pages in the site, all of them filled with many Web Parts. But only a handful (less than ten) of pages have been reported with this behavior.

As far as I am aware, all of my content editors are following the same procedure to add these Web Parts to the page using the Design view. Nobody is doing anything differently, or manually creating items in the Editable Web Parts list via that Advanced area.

We've guessed that this may be happening when multiple editors are editing the same piece of content, as we tend to notice the stale entry after a bunch of editors have been active in the system. It's a subjective guess though - all attempts to re-create the issue with multiple editors working at the same time on the same Web Parts have not been able to successfully recreate an item in the list.

Also not sure if it matters, but I am only getting reports of this happening on a single Web Part -- a custom sub-class of the Kentico WYSIWYG editor.  This may not be related, but I figured it's something that might be a clue. It's also the most-used Web Part we're utilizing, so it may just be statistics that it's the one we've noticed.

Any ideas on where to start looking? Thanks!

Running Kentico version 11.

Answer (score 0):

Kentico maps the editable text and editable images based on the webpart's ID.  So if you change a page template for a page (which isn't too common) and have editable text webparts in the same place BUT with different ID's, the content will be mapped to those respective webparts.

By default, Kentico is set up to do some caching.  It' not very aggressive but it is set up by default.  If you did not implement your site the webpart or the page could also be set up for their own individual caching so you might want to check the pages General tab for this as well as the Performance properties of the editable text webparts.

Comment: Thanks, Brenden!

I've done some testing with changing the page template, and that 
doesn't seem to have affected the the "Editable web parts" list.

Also double checked the "Output cache" on the Page -- all values set to "No".   Web parts only have "Partial cache dependencies" checked.  Any other places for me to check?

Comment: Changing ONLY the template will NOT have an effect on the list.  You need to change the template AND make a content change.  If your editable text webparts have different ID's it will save that webparts ID in the list along with its content.  So if you changed the template and updated some content, then changed the template again for that page and added/modified some content it would show that new ID in the list.  A better option is to use custom page types vs. editable text.  Editable text webparts content cannot be reused across the site and hard to maintain.